# Custom OK google command

Tags: google-voice-actions, ok-google

How do we make OK Google to accept custom commands?

Our requirement is simple, we want something like "Appname keyword" to get results and show on our app. Ok Google works with Search for Keyword on Appname, but its too hard since we have to be very fast to make it work, otherwise it searches on web.

I see here, "Note: We are not accepting requests for Custom Voice Actions. Stay tuned to Voice Actions - Google Developers and +GoogleDevelopers for product updates."
https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions
Is there any workaround or other possible actions that I am unaware of?

Comment: Not a full answer since I'm not entirely sure how this works and this may not be what you want, but building Actions on Google allow the user to communicate with your action by saying something like "Let me talk to <whatever your action is called>". Then the user will communicate to your action and your action can do stuff. Once engaged in the action, your action can then display your app or something like that.

Comment: [Here](http://ok-google.io/) is the unofficial supposedly complete collection and customisations- see if you can tweak your needs some way

Comment: *Go Go  <app name>* brings up results for that app